# browser gets hang/freezes while entering special characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I allowed english along with other language unicode to enter in textbox and restricted special characters, but when i enter special characters the browser gets freezes and unresponsive, below the used combined regex for english and kannada language.

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExpRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="valdn-color" ControlToValidate="txtRemarks" ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets, Numbers and Special Characters like - . / , : () are allowed in Remarks"
                                    SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="KSEI_LP"  ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z-,./(): \r\n\u200D\u0C80-\u0CFF]+)+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

is this pattern even correct

```
ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z-,./(): \r\n\u200D\u0C80-\u0CFF]+)+$"
```

i even tried blocking special characters using java script, but its not working

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function checkSpcialChar(e) {
           alert();
           var k = e.keyCode;
           if ((k == 39) || (k >= 219 && k <= 222) || (k == 187) || (k == 189)) {
               return false;
           }
           else {
               return true;
           }
   </script>
```

How to validate special characters and allow the mentioned characters, help me out guys!

Comment: `+)+` seems precarious. Remove the capture group because it is causing unnecessary overhead. Besides that, it's not freezing my browser at https://regex101.com/r/7ZYsVF/1. What browser are you using? Is your computer a potato?

Comment: nope not potato it seems

Comment: Check your web browser console for errors. I would bet that there is much more going on than the regex especially since it's ASP

Comment: Does `ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9,./(): \r\n\u200D\u0C80-\u0CFF-]+$"` work?

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to filter the bad characters.  The bad ones are very likely those that do not comply with UTF-8.  I'm presuming that is the unicode encoding you are using since the others are rare now.  UTF-8 characters are encoded as follows, where the x's represent the bits of the unicode code-point:

0xxxxxxx
110xxxxx10xxxxxx
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

Note that chars starting with 10 are illegal.  Some of these are defined in the popular ISO-8859-1 standard, but NOT those in the range 0x80 - 0x9f.  Sadly, Microsoft implemented some glyphs in that range.  The left-leading double quote (aka "[the evil] smart quote"), 0x93 is the most egregious.  I suspect that the reason is that it maps to the XOFF character (0x13, aka "control S") WITH THE MSb SET TO 1 making it 0x93.  I worked on a system (VxWorks based) that locked-up when 0x93 was entered and the only way to unlock it was to enter 0x91 (the left-leading single quote; the XON character (0x11, aka "control Q") WITH THE MSb SET TO 0 making it 0x91).  The same system responded to normal XON/XOFF, and in fact both could be set at the same time, in which case both forms of XON would be needed to unlock it.